# What is the difference between a frame of reference and a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

So I understand that vectors are entities that exist in a vector space independently of of any basis we choose, therefore the magnitude of a vector will be a scalar. When studying non-inertial frames however this appears to break down. If there was a vector $ \mathbf{V} $ that pointed normal to the surface of the Earth which is rotating with an angular velocity $ \mathbf{\Omega} $, an observer stationary in the Earth frame would say

$$ \frac{d \mathbf{V}}{dt} = 0, $$

however a stationary observer external to Earth would say

$$ \frac{d \mathbf{V}}{dt} = \mathbf{\Omega} \times \mathbf{V}. $$

The magnitudes of these velocity vectors $\frac{d \mathbf{V}}{dt} $ disagree. If they are describing the same object in the same vector space how can this be?

However if the observers frames were rotated an angle $\theta$ w.r.t. each other, or translated w.r.t. each other, both observers would agree on $\frac{d \mathbf{V}}{dt} $. It seems that some frame transformations preserve scalars and others don't.

What is the difference between a frame of reference and a vector space, and why do they disagree sometimes and other times not?

Comment: A priori, frames of reference and vector spaces have nothing in common. So to explain difefrences, one would first have to show that vector spaces are good tools to describe the world from any frame of reference; this would require a flat Universe, though.

Comment: A basic vector space structure does not allow for measurements of magnitude: length, etc. You need something like a norm or an inner-product for that.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$ or  $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$, a "frame of reference" will be an origin point $p_0$ plus an (orthogonal) basis of the space. The distinction affine space/vector space becomes clear with affine subspaces, for example a given line through $p_0$. Homothetic transformations (translation composed with a an orthogonal linear transformation) preserve norm of vectors, up to multiplication by a constant. In special and general relativity it will become more complicated, considering non-linear transformations of the space.